# Import data from Json to Excel after cleaning text and stopword removal with Python

Tags: python, json, excel, special-characters

I have Json file that contains data I've scraped from a website using Scrapy, my next step is to clean the data text from special characters and stopwords, and save them in Excel file for another step.
The data is like:

```
{"title": ["\u2605\u2605 The New J7 - Social Offer \u2605\u2605"], "seller": ["Galaxy"]}
```

What I need to do:

1. Read each item
2. Remove special characters, which I don't know how to read because they are decoded like this: \u2605\u2605
3. Remove stop words
4. Save the new data in Excel file

I've read a lot of threads about importing Json to Excel but all declare a way of importing it all at once in whole block without modifying the data.

**EDIT:**

Here is my final code that reads the json file, edit the values and save them to excel, I hope it will help others too.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re
import codecs

data = ""
stopwords_list = stopwords.words('english')

with codecs.open("data.json", 'r', 'utf8') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

for item in data:
    for key in item:
        if key == "title":
            temp = str(item[key]).lower()
            temp = re.sub('[`~!@#$^&*()\-_=+{};:\'",<.>/?\\|\[\]★]', '', temp)
            temp = ' '.join([word for word in temp.split() if word not in stopwords_list])
            item[key] = temp

with codecs.open('new_data.json', 'w', 'utf8') as new_data_file:
    json.dump(data, new_data_file)

df = pd.read_json(codecs.open('new_data.json','r','utf-8'))

df.to_excel('out.xlsx')
```

Comment: So... what do you need from us?

Comment: What I've mentioned in the steps: how to read the items from json one by one, clean the text, and save it in excel?

Comment: @Max Thanks, I'm new to python, and I really googled, a lot, but I will try what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

pandas is your friend in this case.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('{"title": ["\u2605\u2605 The New J7 - Social Offer \u2605\u2605"], "seller": ["Galaxy"]}')
# Remove unneeded special characters by encoding to ascii and then recoding to utf-8
df.title = df.title.str.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
df.title = df.title.str.decode('utf-8')

# Removing stopwords - you need a list called stopwords defining your stopwords
df.title = df.title.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stopwords)]))

# write to excel
df.to_excel('out.xlsx')
```

To get a list of stopwords, if you don't have one already, you should investigate [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: Thanks! this works great for special characters and stopwords, however it ignores also non-English letters like ä,ö... how to overcome this?

Comment: Sorry, In that case, one option is to write a list of characters that you accept and keep characters that are in that list. Instead of going back and forth from ascii. Someone with more expertise in localisation than me may know a way to get such a list without writing it yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171095/python-efficient-method-to-remove-all-non-letters-and-replace-them-with-unders this answer probably helps

Comment: Thanks for your time, I did as you suggested, and I figured a complete way to read the file, edit it and save it to excel, it works very well now, except for one obstacle, it's removing the numbers, even though there is nothing mentions removing numbers in my scrip. I've edited my question and added the final script.

Comment: It's the (-) symbol, I should put a backslash before it, now it works perfectly.